# CNAME Wildcards Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, cname-record, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I'm looking to set up a wildcard cname on a FQDN but cant seem to get it to work.

This is what i'm trying to achive:

```
A Record : domain.co.uk : my.ip.address.1
A Record : en.domain.co.uk : my.ip.address.1
cname : www.*.en.domain.co.uk : --> uk.domain.co.uk
```

I'm reasonably new to all this kind of thing, so it's pretty probably pretty straight forward. The number of sites forbids the use of multiple IP addresses.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Windows DNS server can handle CNAME records which point only to A records by default.

Not sure what windows version you are usin, but you can try to enable support via registry setting as described in technet article for Windows 2000

REG_DWORD LooseWildcarding=1

at

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters

check docs there http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940790.aspx

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Kinda, is there any windows-server compatible DNS managment software which can handle the above scenario?

Do you have any reccomendations in achieving the above?

Comment: nice edit :), I did read that article this morning, but unabale to test until this evening as it requires a DNS service restart.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk label in a wilcard record *must* be the left-most label.

So using `www.*.en.example.com` is illegal, but `*.en.example.com` is fine.  Note also that the wildcard matches one *or more* labels.